# How to insert array value into single column and single row in php

Tags: php

**I want to insert array value into database single row and column**

```
$str_accommodation_level = "SELECT * FROM interest";
$query_accommodation_level = $dbcon->query($str_accommodation_level);
while ($accommodation_level = $query_accommodation_level->fetch_array()) {
    $level_from = 'type' . $accommodation_level['id'];
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$level_from])) {
        $level_data += '<span>' . $_COOKIE[$level_from] . '</span> <br>';
    }
    print $level_data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for registering on Stack Overflow. In order to get answers to your problem, please mention in your question which database table needs to be updated, which column in that table, and with which variable. The piece of code you have included does not give any indication about that, it seems to read something from a cookie and print it, which is unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php `implode`. The `implode()` function returns a `string` from the elements of an `array`.

```
$arr = array('1','2','3','4');
$str=implode(",",$arr);
```

or insert like that :-

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1)
VALUES ('$str')
```

Comment: yes, now i am trying - Rahautos 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have been solved this problem with your answer. Thanks - @Rahautos

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also  [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @OoAungHtetPaing

Comment: Now i accepted answer. Thank for your help :)  - @Rahautos

Answer (score -1):

Here I am selecting multiple files form dropdown, I am storing those in array then updating into database.Here filename is name of select tag.

```
 @$filename= $_POST['filename'];
    $title = implode(',',@$filename);
    $sql .="INSERT INTO createtest_filename(id,filename) VALUES('".$max_id."','".$title."');";
```